# How can I address a specific post on a Stack Overflow page (such as addressable in HTML tags with #)?

Tags: discussion

Suppose we have a Stack Overflow page with lots of solutions in replies or discussion. How do we address a specific reply / answer (with its own number of votes) when giving somebody a link?

Comment: Click on the "share" link.